# Class Repositories does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, repository

EDIT: added app/route.php

i am trying to understand the concept of testing in laravel 4. i was following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-laravel-controllers--net-31456) tutorial.

In the Repositories topic, it is mentioned that we must create a custom interface in the app/repository folder, create a class (which will implement the interface) and then dump-autoload the composer. We will use this class in our controller.

So i created the interface

```
<?php

# app/repositories/CategoryRepositoryInterface.php

interface CategoryRepositoryInterface {
    public function all();
    public function find($id);
    public function create($input);  
}
```

then created the class which implements this interface

```
<?php

# app/repositories/EloquentCategoryRepository.php

namespace Repositories

use Repositories\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Category;

class EloquentCategoryRepository implements CategoryRepositoryInterface {

    public function __construct(Category $category){
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return $category->all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return $category->find($id);
    }

    public function create($input)
    {
        return $category->create($input);
    }
}
```

dump autoloaded it, then tried to use it in my controller

```
<?php

# app/controllers/CategoryController.php

use Repositories\CategoryRepositoryInterface as Category;

class CategoryController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(Category $category){
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory(){  
        $categories = $this->category->all();
        return View::make('dashboard.showcategories')->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    public function editCategory($id){
        $category = $this->category->find($id);
        return View::make('dashboard.editcategory')->with('category', $category);

    }

    public function updatecategory(){
        //print_r(Input::all());
        $category = $this->category->find(Input::get('id'));

        $category->category_name = Input::get('category_name');
        $category->options = Input::get('options');

        $category->save();
        Session::flash('message', 'Category Updated Successfully');
        return Redirect::route('categories');
        //<center><a href="{{url('category')}}">(Back)</a></center>
    }

    public function deleteCategory($id){
        $category = $this->category->find($id)->delete();
        Session::flash('message', 'Category Deleted Successfully');

        return Redirect::route('categories');
    }

//----------Showing and progressing New category form---------------//
    public function getCategoryForm(){
        return View::make('dashboard.addcategoryform');
    }

    public function postCategoryForm(){
        if(Input::get('category_name')!="" && Input::get('options')!==""){

                $category = new Category;
                $category->category_name = Input::get('category_name');
                $category->options = Input::get('options');
                $category->save();
                Session::flash('message', 'Category Added Successfully');

                return Redirect::route('categories');

        }else return Redirect::to('addcategory');
    }
//----------(End) Showing and progressing category form---------------//

}
```

Then used App::bind() in the route file

```
App::bind(
                'Repositories\CategoryRepositoryInterface',
                'Repositories\EloquentCategoryRepository'
            );
```

But it's showing an error

```
ReflectionException

Class Repositories\CategoryRepositoryInterface does not exist
```

What am i doing wrong?

here's the route file:

```
<?php



Route::get('/', array('as'=>'getlogin', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@getLogin'));
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'getlogin', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@getLogin'));
Route::post('login', array('as'=>'postlogin', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@postLogin'));


Route::get('test', array('as'=>'test', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@test'));
Route::post('test', array('as'=>'testpost', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@postTest'));

Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', array('as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@dashboard'));
    Route::get('users', array('as'=>'users', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@users'));
        Route::get('users/delete/{userid?}',array('as'=>'deleteuser', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@delete'));
        Route::get('users/contacts/{userid?}', array('as'=>'contacts', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@contacts'));
    Route::get('geo', array('as'=>'geo', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@geo'));



    //---------------------------------Categories Routes--------------------------//
    Route::get('categories', array('as'=>'categories', 'uses'=>'Repositories\CategoryController@getCategory'));
        Route::group(array('prefix'=>'categories'), function(){

            App::bind(
                'Repositories\CategoryRepositoryInterface',
                'Repositories\EloquentCategoryRepository'
            );

            Route::get('addcategory',array('as'=>'getcategoryform', 'uses'=>'Repositories\CategoryController@getCategoryForm'));
            Route::post('addcategory', array('as'=>'postcategoryform', 'uses' => 'Repositories\CategoryController@postCategoryForm'));

            Route::get('edit/{id}', array('as'=>'editcategory', 'uses'=>'Repositories\CategoryController@editCategory'));
            Route::post('updatecategory', array('as'=>'updatecategory', 'uses'=>'Repositories\CategoryController@updatecategory'));
            Route::get('deletecategory/{id}', array('as'=>'deletecategory', 'uses'=>'Repositories\CategoryController@deleteCategory'));
        });
    //----------------------------------End categories-----------------------------//

    Route::get('dashboard/hoots', array('as'=>'hoots', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@hoots'));
    Route::get('dashboard/uniqueusers', array('as'=>'uniqueusers', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@uniqueUsers'));


    Route::get('logout', array('as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'dashboardController@logout'));
});
```

Comment: Can you check your composer/autoload_classmap.php. Your class should be in there and the namespace should be correct.

Comment: yes i guess it's there. It contains a line:

'Repositories\\CategoryRepositoryInterface' => $baseDir . '/app/repositories/CategoryRepositoryInterface.php',

Comment: Can you add your `routes.php` code too?

Comment: Ha, cool you got it working!!! Well done man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the namespaces so your files are all in the same namespace, so this is not a problem anymore.

app/repositories/CategoryRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php namespace Repositories;

interface CategoryRepositoryInterface {
    public function all();
    public function find($id);
    public function create($input);  
}
```

app/repositories/EloquentCategoryRepository.php

```
<?php namespace Repositories;

use Category;

class EloquentCategoryRepository implements CategoryRepositoryInterface {

    public function __construct(Category $category){
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return $category->all();
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return $category->find($id);
    }

    public function create($input)
    {
        return $category->create($input);
    }
}
```

app/controllers/CategoryController.php

```
<?php namespace Repositories;

use CategoryRepositoryInterface as Category;
use BaseController, View, Input, Session, Redirect;

class CategoryController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(Category $category){
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory(){  
        $categories = $this->category->all();
        return View::make('dashboard.showcategories')->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    public function editCategory($id){
        $category = $this->category->find($id);
        return View::make('dashboard.editcategory')->with('category', $category);

    }

    public function updatecategory(){
        //print_r(Input::all());
        $category = $this->category->find(Input::get('id'));

        $category->category_name = Input::get('category_name');
        $category->options = Input::get('options');

        $category->save();
        Session::flash('message', 'Category Updated Successfully');
        return Redirect::route('categories');
        //<center><a href="{{url('category')}}">(Back)</a></center>
    }

    public function deleteCategory($id){
        $category = $this->category->find($id)->delete();
        Session::flash('message', 'Category Deleted Successfully');

        return Redirect::route('categories');
    }

//----------Showing and progressing New category form---------------//
    public function getCategoryForm(){
        return View::make('dashboard.addcategoryform');
    }

    public function postCategoryForm(){
        if(Input::get('category_name')!="" && Input::get('options')!==""){

                $category = new Category;
                $category->category_name = Input::get('category_name');
                $category->options = Input::get('options');
                $category->save();
                Session::flash('message', 'Category Added Successfully');

                return Redirect::route('categories');

        }else return Redirect::to('addcategory');
    }
//----------(End) Showing and progressing category form---------------//

}
```

Comment: It is an eloquent model class stored in apps/models. The tutorial(mentioned above) says that we should not include a model directly into the controller. So that's why i changed my current code and added namespace, interface etc.

Comment: After Edit: Class 'Repositories\BaseController' not found :D

Comment: Sorry, you have to add it in the `use` like so `use BaseController;` this is for any class you use outside of your namespace. So you will get more! Just add them to that list like so `use BaseController, Session, Etc`. I added them to the example. This is a very elegant way to see what classes you use in your code, all stowed away in one place.

Comment: After adding, `use BaseController, View, Input, Session, Redirect;`, it says Class CategoryController does not exist . WTF :D

Comment: Haha yep, welcome to namespacing! ;) I will have another look. From which file?

Comment: :D `/var/www/Hututoo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php`

Comment: This means it's being called outside of the namespace! I'll find it! :)

Comment: I know! In the router you must add the namespace 'Repositories\CategoryController@...' or any other place were the controller is being called, but I guess the router.

Comment: added `Repositories\` to each route calling the CategoryController like `Repositories\CategoryController@getCategoryForm`. Now it says `Class Repositories\EloquentCategoryRepository does not exist` . i will read a bit about namespace. Thanks :).

Comment: No that's not good. :) The controller is called somewhere. From that place it is probably called like `CategoryController` but this should be `Repositories\CategoryController`. Can you do a full textsearch through you project for `CategoryController`?

Comment: Not possible now as my job hours are over... Will try to update 2mrw.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In your composer.json file, are you autoloading the "repositories" directory?

EDIT: Looks like you aren't using the Repositories namespace in your Interface

Should be:

```
# app/repositories/CategoryRepositoryInterface.php

namespace Repositories;

interface CategoryRepositoryInterface {
    public function all();
    public function find($id);
    public function create($input);  
}
```

Comment: added namespace Repositories, dump autoloaded composer. Still same error.